Movie about an online stream
A couple of people move into a new place. They decide to check out an online stream that's become popular. It watches a house with other people living in it. They become obsessed with watching these other people, watching them 24-7. And then people start getting killed in the stream.

 Turns out the house is the same house they just moved into, and the events happened just before they moved in. And maybe the people watching the feed are the killers, or the people themselves, or something? A little hazy on the specifics. Anyway, it's a big mind-blowing ending.

I saw this a while back (maybe 5 years ago). No idea when it was released, though. Oh, an it's not Bollywood. American/British English. Can't remember its name, though it's one of my all-time faves!

This was asked here before, but I can't find the question (or remember the movie). :( I'll look harder.

@Richard No, it's not Big Brother. I must've missed the news that they were being killed off... ;P

@Whothehellisthat could you tell us around what time the movie was released . Also the plot you have specified is similar to 13B , a bollywood movie.

I watched it maybe 5 years ago? No idea when it was released, though. Oh, an it's not Bollywood. American/British English.

Clarifications: The people on the stream start getting killed, or start killing each other perhaps.

Four Boxes (2009)  maybe?

Trevor (Justin Kirk) and Rob (Sam Rosen), begin work on their next job: liquidating the possessions of a recently deceased suburbanite. Things get complicated when Amber, Rob’s current girlfriend and Trevor’s ex, a young redhead named Amber (Terryn Westbrook), enters into the fray. The love triangle is further twisted when they become obsessed with an web-cam site called Fourboxes.tv where a disturbing individual named Havoc seems to be creating a weapons of mass destruction. The more they get drawn into the events of the web-cam site the more unraveled their world becomes until they become convinced that Havoc is preparing to detonate his bombs on a multi-city level. 

Trailer

We have a winner! Thanks so much for your help!!

Sounds like Antisocial (2013)

Sam (Michelle Mylett) is a young college student that has recently been dumped by her boyfriend via video chat. To lift her spirits Sam decides to take her friend Mark (Cody Ray Thompson) up on his offer to attend a small New Year's Eve pre-party. Once there, things seem to be going well until their friend Jed (Adam Christie) turns on the television, which displays a news story about a seemingly isolated act of violence. The attack proves to be not so isolated as the group soon finds themselves the focus of an attack. Through the news and social media sites the group discovers that there is a new disease that causes various different symptoms, one of which is uncontrolled violence. They board themselves up in their lodgings and initially they believe that they will be fine until some of their friends begin to show symptoms of the disease. The film also follows Brian (Eitan Shalmon), a friend of Jeb's that is confined to his dorm room and decides that he will chronicle the happenings online via a social media site named Social Redroom.


That's not the one, either. Thanks for your help!

Sounds like a good movie. Is it My Little Eye?

Five young people apply to live in an isolated house together for six
  months whilst their every move is filmed by numerous cameras. Each has
  their reason for wanting to be there - fame, money, adventure. The
  prize - $1 million. The rules - if one person leaves, everyone loses.
  It becomes the ultimate morality test. When Danny's beloved
  grandfather dies, does his greed overcome his love? When the skittish
  Emma finds blood on her pillow why does she still stay behind? And
  what dark secret does the house harbour that leaves them feeling as
  though they're being watched by more than just a million pairs of
  eyes?


I don't think that's it because I'm sure I've seen what the original poster's describing and I've never seen My Little Eye (although they could of course have similar plots).

No, it's not My Little Eye. This film is all told from the point of view of the watchers of the stream, not in the house where the murders are going on.
